# How to replace float with binary matrix in pandas dataframe for keras model?

Tags: python, pandas, keras

For a school project it is required to train a keras model to the [Titanic](https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv) dataset.
I'm trying to encode categorical columns to a binary matrix and replace the current string values, sadly I can't manage it. In the example underneath i'm encoding 'male' and 'female' to binary representation.

Result of to_categorical:

```
[[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 ...
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]]
```

Result when replacing current values:

```
0      0.0
1      1.0
2      1.0
3      1.0
4      0.0
      ... 
622    0.0
623    0.0
624    1.0
625    1.0
626    0.0
```

Desired result:

```
0      [0. 1.]
1      [1. 0.]
2      [1. 0.]
3      [1. 0.]
4      [0. 1.]
      ... 
622    [0. 1.]
623    [0. 1.]
624    [1. 0.]
625    [1. 0.]
626    [0. 1.]
```

I'm very new to Python and Keras. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['sex', 'class', 'deck', 'embark_town', 'alone']
NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ['age', 'n_siblings_spouses', 'parch', 'fare']

df = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv')
properties = list(df.columns.values)
properties.remove('survived')


def transform_fn(label):
    vec = label_encoder.fit_transform(df[label])
    categorical = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(vec)
    print(label + ": ", categorical)
    df[label] = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(vec)


for c in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
    transform_fn(c)

x = df[properties]
y = df['survived']

print(x['sex'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `pd.get_dummies(df)`. This function will convert categorical variable into dummy/indicator variables.

So, if you have `Sex` column `pd.get_dummies` will return another DataFrame with `Sex_Male` and `Sex_Female` columns.

But such transformation gives redundant information. And because of that data scientists othen use `pd.get_dummies(df, drop_first=True)` to to get rid of the first columns, like `Sex_Male` in the example.

And later you can use `df[<Col_name>].astype(<type>)` to get any type you want.

To get dummies only from one column, you do the following:

```py
df_sex = pd.get_dummies(df['sex'])
df_tmp = df.drop('sex', axis=1)
df = pd.merge(df_sex, df_tmp, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: I've tried it, it gives me the Dataframe. But how do I replace the values I had. I've tried df['sex'] = pd.get_dummies(df['sex']). Yet this just replace male and female with the 1 and 0's from the first column of the dataset.

Comment: Besides sex there are a lot more labels like 'class', 'embark_town', 'deck', etc. So when I try that it throws all the seperate columns together like: 'sex_female', 'sex_male', 'class_First', 'class_Second', 'class_Third', 'deck_A', 'deck_B', 'deck_C', 'deck_D', 'deck_E', 'deck_F'. That doesn't seem like the solution.

Comment: I changed the answer. Take a look